# Condition based builder in Java

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I have a field that needs to be checked. If the field matches put it to builder if not, don't put it to builder.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class UserSchool {
    private final Long UserId;
    private final String school;
    private final Optional<String> lunch;

}
```

I need to check if user belongs to "high school", then add parameter lunch to builder. If user doesn't belong to "high school" don't add parameter to builder.

```
if(user.school.name().equals(School.high_school.name())){
            Deposit.builder()
                    .lunch(request.getLounchName());
        }

UserSchool userSchool = UserSchool.builder()
                .UserId(Long.valueOf(user.UserId.id))
                .school(request.getUserSchool())
                .build();
```

I have come up with this code above and lunch parameter is `null` although it should be there.

When I add it to builder without if statement like this:

```
UserSchool userSchool = UserSchool.builder()
                .UserId(Long.valueOf(user.UserId.id))
                .school(request.getUserSchool())
                .lunch(request.getLounchName())
                .build();
```

It works but I need to be able to check condition.
What am I missing?

Comment: `Deposit.builder().lunch(request.getLounchName());` shouldn't you do something with the result of this? Like putting it in a variable?

Comment: Maybe a lambda, `.lunch(request::getLunchName)`, so only when high school, `getLunchName` is called (combinable with Optional). Everything else seems too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use an Optional type as a class field, generally only return types or wrappers to nullable return types.

If I understand the question, though, you're looking for this

```
UserSchool.Builder builder = UserSchool.builder()
                .UserId(Long.valueOf(user.UserId.id))
                .school(request.getUserSchool());
if (condition) {
   builder.lunch(..);
}
UserSchool userSchool = builder.build();
```

Or

```
String lunch = condition ? "some value" : null;
UserSchool.Builder builder = UserSchool.builder()
                .UserId(Long.valueOf(user.UserId.id))
                .lunch(lunch)
                .school(request.getUserSchool())
               .build();
```

Or simply add a method to the class, not use a nullable field

```
public Optional<String> getLunch() {
    return condition ? Optional.of("some value") : Optional.empty();
}
```

The problem with the if statement before the builder is that you've used some other builder, but never captured its return value to use later on

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked. I checked it inline if/else condition and then passed it to builder as variable. :)